# return value from forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need alert with value from input in **this** form.
When I'm click on link (click me) I want to see alert with value from this form.
Please help me.

```
<form class='form'>
     <a class='link'>click me</a>
    <input type='text' class='inputs' name='input' value=1/>
</form>

<form class='form'>
     <a class='link'>click me</a>
    <input type='text' class='inputs' name='input' value=2/>
</form>

<form class='form'>
     <a class='link'>click me</a>
    <input type='text' class='inputs' name='input' value=3/>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').click(function(){
        **alert(VALUE FROM THIS .INPUTS);**
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).next().val() );
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u2VGc/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) for that:

```
$('.link').click(function(){
    var val = $(this).next('input').val();
    alert(val);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VDc2/)